# Rollback to kernel 5.8

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I'm quite new here in Ubuntu. So I just recently moved up to Kernel 5.10, about a day ago, since it supports the Realtek ethernet drivers there...When I realized (and checked lately) that it still doesn't have Nvidia driver support causing to display an `ERROR nvidia driver is not loaded ubuntu 20.04`.

I installed the Kernel 5.10 using from this [method](https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu).

I heard that the nvidia driver 455.45.01 does support 5.9 and so the realtek ethernet driver. Is there a way to possibly revert back to Kernel 5.8 *for a meanwhile* to possibly install a 5.9 there?

Thanks and hoping for a thoroughly guide/help on this one.

cheers.

Comment: @Yehuda..Yep. I tried that and still rebooted back to kernel 5.10...Changed the `GRUB_DEFAULT="2"` which is the  5.8.

Comment: @user535733 oh alright. I'll edit it out quickly. I'll add the link on the instructions on how I've done the 'upgrade' thing.

Comment: Egad. Those instructions tell you to do horrible, dangerous things to your system. Do not trust that source any more.

Comment: oh sh*t. :c Well, that didn't go well.

Comment: Anways, on @Yehuda's link...I tried to change the grub default; `GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"` and update it. I got reboot'd but when I run'd the `uname -r`, it still says the kernel 5.10

Comment: I don't see much point trying 5.9 (I'm not sure it was ever packaged). If it doesn't work in 5.8 not 5.10, why would 5.9 be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read your /var/log/dpkg.log to find the exact name(s) of the kernel package(s) that you installed.

   - Shortcut: Use `grep linux /var/log/dpkg.log` to filter for only kernel-related packages.
   - Here's an example line from my own logfile. See the 5.8 kernel package name?

   > 2021-02-09 06:48:06 install **linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic**:amd64  5.8.0-43.49
2. Uninstall those 5.10 kernel packages using those exact package names. Use the format: `sudo apt remove package1 package2 package3 packageN`
3. If you really followed those random instructions from the dirty, dirty internet, then your system is now 20.10 instead of 20.04. Though it was improperly done and you may encounter other problems, and your system might claim to still be 20.04 (it's not). You cannot safely downgrade (though you can backup your data and reinstall 20.04 if you wish, of course).

   - Non-LTS releases lose support and security patches after only 9 months.
   - Mark your calendar: In late April 2021, late October 2021, and late April 2022, you must run `do release-upgrade` to migrate to the next release of Ubuntu. April 2022 (22.04) is the next LTS release.

Comment: Alright. it worked. Thanks. :) I'll also keep in mind about the next LTS release.